# How is density "predicted"?

Tags: synthesis, density

Hassium is predicted to be the densest element at 41 g/cm ^3, but how do you predict something like that? Wikipedia says there have only been 100 hassium atoms made to date and it's half life is less than ten seconds, so I have no idea how a scientist came up with that figure... any insight?

Comment: Perhaps they made educated guesses about the internuclear distance, based on extrapolated data from other transition metals. This could be used to estimate the volume occupied by a given number of the atoms. Calculating the mass for that number of atoms would be trivial. Mass over volume, you have density.

Comment: One could do a calculation, say with density functional theory. One could have an educated guess of what the most likely crystal structure is, with another educated guess on lattice parameter. One could use a dart board.

Comment: You don't need even one real atom to predict anything. The reliability of prediction is another question. Then again, given the extreme instability of the element, it is a prediction that probably will never be verified, so...

Comment: You do a theoretical calculation based on a model that has been verified by  testing, i.e. that correctly predicts the density of other, "similar" elements, which are less elusive.